# electron-forge wont compile component templates from separate HTML files

Tags: angular, electron, electron-forge

I set up a new project with [electron-forge using the angular2 template](https://electronforge.io/templates). It all worked fine but then I tried to move a component template into a separate HTML file.

I simply took the example HTML from  `app.component.ts`, pasted it into a new `app.component.html` in the same dir and in component changed...
`` template: `<h1>template content</h1>` ``
to..
`templateUrl: './app.component.html'`

When I run this now I get the error:

> `Couldn't set selectedTextBackgroundColor from default ()`

and the electron window that starts up just displays an error message about failing to compile the new template HTML.

Is there some configuration needed to work with external templates? Or am I missing something obvious here?

When/if I get this fixed, am I going to run into a similar issue adding external stylesheets using `styleUrls:[]`?

Any advice gladly accepted. My childlike joy at the prospect of creating an electron/angular app has been slowly crushed today by an inability to get anything at all working.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

try with npm run watch to compile de project (if use npm) , worked for me in laravel,

If doesnt use npm , you must compile the template again

good luck